# A Loop unnecessarily requires MessageBox, freezes if removed

Tags: c#, loops, messagebox

I have a C# code that when it runs, it feeds approximately 200 values into separate lines in a multi-line enabled textbox but a messagebox in the middle, which I put just to be sure it's feeding the correct data, now freezes the whole code if removed. I couldn't understand the significance of it, previous textboxes handled heavier loads with little trouble but apparently this one require a short break or at least some sort of human interaction(luckily only pressing the OK button on a messagebox) so I was wondering if there is a solution or a way around it like a similar stop but not requiring my guidance. It's not convenient to press a key 200+ times just to get one group of data out of many.

Below is the code, just in case:

```
if (listBox3.SelectedIndex < 0 || listBox4.SelectedIndex < 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("Select the Chart Parameters(E.g.: BTC-USD)");
}

if (listBox4.GetItemText(listBox4.SelectedItem).Contains(listBox3.GetItemText(listBox3.SelectedItem))) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please select seperate pairs.(E.g.: NOT BTC-BTC but e.g.:BTC-USD)");
}
else
{
    string url = textBox8.Text + listBox3.GetItemText(listBox3.SelectedItem) + listBox4.GetItemText(listBox4.SelectedItem);
    MessageBox.Show(url);
    System.Net.WebClient client8 = new System.Net.WebClient();
    var html = client8.DownloadString(url);

    string s = html.Replace("[[", "[");
    string ss = s.Replace("]]", "]");

    textBox9.Text = ss;

    dynamic obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ss);     //ss is the data
    var timezz = (Int32)obj1.SelectToken("time");
    textBox11.Text = textBox11.Text + timezz;
    var data1m = (string)obj1.SelectToken("data1m");


    ICollection<string> matches =
      Regex.Matches(data1m, @"\[([^]]*)\]", RegexOptions.Multiline)
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
      .ToList();

    foreach (string match in matches) { textBox10.Text += Environment.NewLine + match; }

    for (int i = 1; i < textBox10.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string linebyline = textBox10.Lines[i];
        var resultString = Regex.Match(linebyline, @"\d+").Value;
        //uni_time = resultString;
        var yen = linebyline.Replace(resultString, string.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show(yen);                                        

        /////WHY DOES IT NEEDS TO BE STOPPED BY THIS MSGBOX INORDER2 EXECUTE THE WHOLE CODE???
        //////IF I REMOVE IT, IT FREEZES
        var resultz = yen.Substring(yen.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);
        //uni_vol = resultz;
        var ztring = yen.Replace(resultz, string.Empty);
        //MessageBox.Show(ztring);

        //Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d{1,4})?");

        ICollection<string> mc = Regex.Matches(ztring, @"\d+(\.\d{1,4})?").Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[0].Value)
        .ToList();

        foreach (string m in mc)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(m);
            if (textBox13.Text == string.Empty) { textBox13.Text += m; }
            else
            {
                textBox13.Text += Environment.NewLine + m;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can read it.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception that is stopping the code?

Comment: It's not stopping or giving an error but freezes indefinetely.

Comment: I suspect you have an infinite loop somewhere that you don't notice because the UI is being updated on the same thread which never terminates.  Or do you click the message box 200 times to verify that it terminates properly in that case?

Comment: It's  MessageBox.Show(yen);

Comment: @D Stanley it does terminates properly..I did 200+ time few times, made me question who's compiling who :D

Comment: Can you post some sample input text?

Comment: show where and how this code gets called - is it invoked from an event handler? does multithreading take place? Does it work when you replace the MessageBox by a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)?

Comment: 489.458, 1688, 789.12, 987.2 ......messagebox does no change on any variable. I put it there just to check its outcome

Comment: @dlatikay private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{....here...} letme try that...

Comment: can we not just blame the RegEx and close the question :)
please try the thread.sleep to confirm/rule out some kind of deadlock. The MessageBox will use the message pump of the UI thread, so there might be something interfering with that.

Comment: or, another shot in the blue: maybe there is an event handler on textBox13, which, directly or indirectly, modifies the contents of textBox10, while you are looping over it?

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5) freezed it long enough for ping-pong with server to stop.but it does the job..meaning messagebox had no influence on the value.which is weird because the first few seconds it lets the ping-pong but later blocks it and disconnects. Also when I was confirming each line by pressing OK on that unwanted messagebox, it didn't affect the ping-pong with server

Comment: DownloadString is a synchronous call: how is there client<>server traffic going on once you're inside the loop? The sleep is not a solution, it just shows that there is a timing/threading issue. don't take this productive even if it appears to work now.